# RoboMongo - Cannot Remove Documents from Collection

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I'm using RoboMongo to delete a number of documents that match a query. However, it is saying no documents have been delete with the following:

```
db.getCollection('assets').remove( { "source": "red" } );
```

However, this works perfectly:

```
db.getCollection('assets').find( { "source": "red" } );
```

and displays all the records with the source "red".

Is there any reason why the records are not being removed and robomongo is just outputting 0?

Kind Regards,

Comment: Perhaps there is a document with a field that has a space character?

Comment: @chridam but the find function works perfect

Comment: I have this same problem now.

Answer (score 4):

`DeleteMany` worked for me: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.deleteMany/#db.collection.deleteMany

```sh
db.getCollection('assets').deleteMany({source: 'red'})
```

This should return

```
/* 1 */
{
    "acknowledged" : true,
    "deletedCount" : number // which is the number of documents deleted
}
```

[image: example screenshot]

From the above query, I removed all passengers that the snapshot id is `5c749daee3a0ec00047ffd5c`

Answer (score 3):

Are you running with a replica set?  If so make sure that you are running the remove command on the primary node.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one:

```
db.assets.remove( {source : "red" } )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query:

```
db.assets.remove( { "source":"red"} )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `double quotes` around the `field name` and try something like this:

```
db.getCollection('assets').remove( { source: "red" } );
```